# Silverlight or browser losing cookies on hyperlinked windows?

Tags: silverlight, browser, cookies

Am using Silverlight 4 hosted in an ASP.NET MVC page, e.g. http://test.example.com/main. I make a call to the server from Silverlight using WCF and get some values back. One of these values I write as a cookie using:

```
HtmlPage.Document.SetProperty("cookie", newCookie);
```

I can then view the cookie text using:

```
MessageBox.Show(HtmlPage.Document.Cookies);
```

I can see various cookies, including the one I just created, so looks like it was created ok.

From within the SL app, I display some hyperlinks. When the user clicks on this it will display the link in a new browser window. The links go to the same domain, e.g. http://test.example.com/viewdoc?1233

The new cookie that was created is not being passed in the request. The other cookies that were originally there are being passed. I don't see how its a crossdomain policy issue since they are going to the same domain. It doesn't matter what browser I use (Safari, Firefox, IE8, IE6), they all exhibit the same problem, so it doesn't seem to be an IE8 issue that I saw on other similar issues.

So where is my cookie going?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Verify that the [path](http://www.cookiecentral.com/faq/) property of the cookie is not set to certain page only:

> The path parameter is potentially the
>   most useful of the 4 optional cookie
>   settings. It sets the URL path the
>   cookie is valid within. Pages outside
>   of that path cannot read or use the
>   cookie. If Path is not set explicitly, 
>   then it defaults to the URL path of the 
>   document creating the cookie.

Comment: Thank you so much. This was indeed the problem.